# Import MySQL DB Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am moving a xampp locahost site to hostinger. While importing, the following SQL error occurred:

```
INSERT INTO  `cds` (  `titel` ,  `interpret` ,  `jahr` ,  `id` ) 
VALUES 
 ('Beauty',  'Ryuichi Sakamoto', 1990, 1), 
 ('Goodbye Country (Hello Nightclub)',  'Groove Armada', 2001, 4), 
 ('Glee',  'Bran Van 3000', 1997, 5);
```

**Error:**

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Truncate the Table and try again...

Comment: can you share your mysql dump?

Answer (score 0):

primary key must be unique. you should uncheck "auto increment" configuration for your primary key(id) or check is there any id equal to '1'